# How to design similar structure tables in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have two types of objects to store in mysql. One is "event", which has attributes of time, title, content, owner, etc.; the other is "activity", which has attributes of time, title, content, owner, maximum attendee number, ticket price, etc.

I need to query both events and activities of an owner user and display them on his calendar. So what is the optimal design for these two types - do I use two tables for them (and use complicated query like join); or do I use one table and a "is_event" flag column to indicate the type (and allow empty "maximum attendee number" & "ticket price" column for events)?
What is your experience for this situation considering database performance, cache, programming difficulties, etc?

Comment: Use 2 tables. A `join` is not complicated.

Comment: quite possibly more than 2, hard to say based on the information provided

Comment: if indexed properly joins are as fast as selecting from a single table

Comment: @mrmoment: No, not if you have proper indexes on the table. Do you think google has a single big table? No, they join a lot and are really fast with billions of records.

Comment: my biggest join has 2k tables :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 different tables. It is a cleaner design, seperates the different data and does not need so much column that are always null for certain types.

You can then select the data with a query like this

```
select u.name,
       e.title as event_title,
       a.title as activity_title
from `user` u
left join `event` e on u.id = e.owner
left join `activity` a on u.id = a.owner
```

Comment: @mrmoment: See my comment above